# I am using javascript window object function to timely call rails controller on when the tab running application gains focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

while testing this code I found it to be working absolutely fine with the firefox browser checked it with firebug but it doesn't work with chrome browser
here is my code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onfocus = startCheck;
        var dualLogin;
            function startCheck() {
            dualLogin = setInterval(function () {
                checkTable();
            }, 20000);
        }
        function checkTable() {
            $.ajax({
                url:"<%= url_for :controller => 'xyz',:action => 'abc'%>",
                cache:false,
                dataType:'json',
                success:function (data) {
                    if (data.status=='dual')
                    {
                        logout();
                    }
                }
            })
        }
        window.onblur = stopCheck;
        function stopCheck() {
            window.clearInterval(dualLogin);
        }
        function logout(){
            alert('you are to be logged out');
            window.location.replace("/registeration_page");
        }                                       
    </script>
```

can any one help thanks in advance.

Comment: There are issues with your code: 1st, startCheck is been given to onfocus before it's declaration, not sure what is the correct JS semantics to that and even worst the semantics can be different from browser to browser. So move `window.onfocus = startCheck;` to after the function declaration.

Comment: I tested above code and it seems to be working fine with Chrome. stopCheck and startCheck are being called on respective events fire. Is there any other problem?

Comment: 2nd add `console.log`s to start and stopCheck and make sure they do are invoked in chrome.

Comment: Mind that chrome also has the developer tools, its equivalent for firebug.

Comment: @Shusl can you tell me you chrome version and operating system.

Comment: @pedrofurla i know chrome about chrome developers tool I checked for ajax call at console but they were not their.

Comment: @vidur: Chrome v = 21.0.1180.89 m on windows8. But I have used onfocus and onblur for my applications and I never faced such problem. You should make sure that event methods are not getting overridden by other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a [jsfiidle](http://jsfiddle.net/gryfC). 
have a look. click on result box for focus and click on other for blur.